# Why all differentials are $0$ for Serre Spectral Sequence of trivial fibration?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences

Consider the fibration $F \hookrightarrow F \times B \to B$.  I understand that if I take kunneth's theorem for granted that the group extensions $F_{n-i,i} \to F_{n-i+1,i-1} \to F_{n-i+1,i-1}/F_{n-i,i}$ associated to the filtration $F_{n,0} \supset ...F_{n-i,i}...$ are all trivial extensions, and that $d_r=0$ for $r>2$.  How can we deduce these two facts without assuming Kunneth's theorem.

For the record, here is the reason why I get these two facts if I assume Kunneth.

---

The action of the fundamental group of the base on the fiber is nontrivial due to the splitting $H_*(F) \to H_*(B)$.
There is always a map $E^\infty \to H_*(E)$, and by kunneth we have the surjective map
$\text{a subgroup of}(E^2= H_*(B,H_*(F))) \to E^\infty \to H_*(E)=\text{(use kunneth)} H_*(B,H_*(F))$ so that the composition is the identity.  Thus the first subgroup is the whole of $E^2$.  Therefore it is not possible that
either the series $H_n(B \times F) = \text{(by convergence of SSS)} im (H_n(B_n \times F) \mapsto  H_n(B \times F))\supset im (H_n(B_{n-1} \times F) \mapsto  im (H_n(B_{n-2} \times F) \mapsto  H_n(B \times F)) \supset  ... H_n(F)$ of group extensions be nontrivial ,
or $d^r$ be nonzero for $r  \geq 2$.

---

I would like to know how to deduce two facts without using Kunneth's theorem, and hence deduce Kunneth's theorem from the SSS of this fibration.

I have a hunch that the proof that the differentials are 0 should be something like "Any map from $E^1_{p+q,q}=C_p(B) \otimes H_q(F) \to E^1_{p-2+q+1,q+1}=C_{p-2}(B) \otimes H_{q+1}(F)$ must be zero because either the domain or codomain is 0 and therefore there is no possible way that this map cannot be 0 after restricting and descending to $E^2$, and hence $d_2=0$.

To show that the series $H_n(B \times F) = \text{(by convergence of SSS)} im (H_n(B_n \times F) \mapsto  H_n(B \times F))\supset im (H_n(B_{n-1} \times F) \mapsto  im (H_n(B_{n-2} \times F) \mapsto  H_n(B \times F)) \supset  ... H_n(F)$

is trivial, I need to show that there is a splitting map $im ( H_*(X_{p}) \mapsto H_*(X)) \to im ( H_*(X_{p-1}) \mapsto H_*(X))$.  I also have a hunch that this should have something to do with the topological splitting $B_n \times F \to B_n$.

Can I have some help with turning my gut feeling into a proof?

Comment: Here is a suggestion: Build an algebraic model of what you would like your spectral sequence to look like and use the comparison theorem to show that its $E_\infty$-term coincides with that of the fibration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am working it out now.  I am using $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients. I expected the extension problem to be trivial because if one assumes  extension problem is trivial and assumes the differentials are 0, one gets that $H_n(B\times F)=\oplus_{p+q=n} E^2_{p+q,q}=\oplus_{p+q=n} H_p(B,H_q(F))$; this yields the correct answer irrespective of the coefficients used - it takes into account the $Tor$ terms.

Comment: Actually good point :) I was missing that the Tor terms are already taken into account there.

Answer (score 1):

The reason all the differentials are 0 is simple.  I'll do it for cohomology because otherwise I need to use the coalgebra structure on homology. 
 We know the elements of $E_r^{0,n}$ are permanent cycles for all $r,n$:  there is an edge map $H^n(E)\to E_\infty^{0,n} \subset E_2^{0,n}=H_n(F)$ which has to be surjective because of the obvious splitting.  Thus $E_\infty^{0,n}= E_2^{0,n}$.

The elements of $E_r^{n,0}$ are automatically permanent cycles.  Thus every element $E_r^{n,m}$ that is a product of cycles is a cycle.  This solves the problem for the coefficients in the rationals.

For coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$, we have an injective map of spectral sequences $E_r \otimes \mathbb{Z}/p \to \epsilon_r$ where $\epsilon$ is the spectral sequence of the fibration with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p$.  Therefore the $d_r$ is 0 modulo p for all $p$ on $E^r$.

This shows that $d_r=0$ for all $r>1$.