# Extension problem for serre spectral sequence of trivial fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences, fibration

Consider the cohomology spectral sequence of the trivial fibration $F \hookrightarrow F \times B \to B$.  I showed in my answer here [Why all differentials are $0$ for Serre Spectral Sequence of trivial fibration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865747/why-all-differentials-are-0-for-serre-spectral-sequence-of-trivial-fibration), that differentials after $d_1$ are 0.

Question:  Why is $Assgrd H^*(B \times F)=H^*(B \times F)$?

I expect the extension problem to be trivial because, if I assume it is then $H^n(E)=\oplus_{p+q=n} H^p(B,H^q(F))$ which takes into account the Tor terms which are $\oplus_{p+q=n} Tor( H^{p+1}(B), H^q(F))$.

I understand why one of the extensions are trivial here:  The extension $0 \to F_{1,n-1} \to F_{0,n}  \to E_{\infty}^{0,n} \subset E_2^{0,n}$ has a splitting because 
$H^n(E)=F_{0,n}  \to E_{\infty}^{0,n} \subset E_2^{0,n}=H^n(F)$ is the edge map, which has the obvious splitting.

Comment: The following argument should work: The serre spectral sequence of the trivial fibration is isomorphic to the spectral sequence of the double complex associated to the two complexes $C*(B)$ and $C*(F)$.  Both the sequences converge to $H*(B \times F)=H*(C*(B) \times C*(F))(eilenberg zilber)$.  $gr H(C*(B))=H*(B)$ and $gr H(C*(F))$ implies that $gr H(C*(B) \otimes C*(F))=H(C*(B) \otimes C*(F))$.